# Correct use-case for redis

Tags: database, node.js, web-applications, nosql, redis

I am totally new to noSQL and have only really dabbled with SQL. However I can clearly see that noSQL is going to be a better fit for my applications data as it doesn't fit the traditional table model.

However I am worried that I am going to invest time in implementing and understanding a solution that will later turn out to be the incorrect fit for my application and not work how I assumed it would.

I am leaning towards [redis](http://redis.io/) - despite not understanding a lot of what I have read about it. I need to know if it is capable of what I want it to do, whether it is a good choice for what I want to do and whether there is anything useful I should know before venturing out with it or that will streamline my process. **My application is written in javaScript and powered by node.js.**

Here is what I need from my database:

**Fast storage of real-time data**, I want to store every action the user makes as they make it. Considering my application requires a high level of user engagement this will be a constant stream of information. I have read redis is an exceptionally fast in-memory database.

**Reliability** - This is an area I hear redis has weaknesses, and people say that it's persistence should not be used for sensitive data. Is it possible to reliably unload a user's data to the disk and reload it when they next return? Would such an operation be fast or slow (I understand this is dependant on the data - but would you personally perform such an operation as I have no idea what to expect?) - perhaps it would be better to store the redis information in an SQL database once the user has finished modifying it?

Expanding on the reliability case, say I have the following key:

`user:id:appData`

Is it possible to delete everything in `user:1:appData` without affecting `user:2:appData` or any other `user:id:appData`?

**Concurrency -** Can redis handle many user's writing to it at the same time? How about querying?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes to all your questions. Redis is a good choice :)

Comment: How much querying do you intend to perform? Do you need to query complicated data? Honestly, I really like redis, but if you already know SQL use that. Also, this question might get different/better answers in _programmers_

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I fear SQL is going to be far too slow for my application and the limited table structure will negatively impact it's functionality. The database will hold mostly JSON objects, and I will let my application logic do most of the heavy lifting. It's mainly for rapidly updating and retrieving data from the database. I will be doing a large amount of querying, almost every single user action will result in a query.

Comment: If you don't really need ACID, and need a _very_ fast key value store, then REDIS is an _excellent_ choice. Especially since most of your data is JSON serialized data. It is great for that.